# Previous activity not getting

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I am working on tab host application containing 4 tabs. Each tab has individual activity that lists items. on item click of each tab takes to another activity displaying details of clicked list item in same tab host screen layout.

If i press back button after clicking an item from tab host, the application exits. But i need to visit the previously reached list and tabs. How to achieve this? Thanks in Advance

This is my Sample Code -

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.list, 
                new String[] { "title","shortdescription"}, 
                new int[] { R.id.titleTextView,R.id.descriptionTextView});
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.statutesListView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String newstitle = hashMap.get("title");
                String newsdesc = hashMap.get("shortdescription");


                //Get the new Activity to tab.

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), detailedview.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("title", newstitle);
                bundle.putString("desc", newsdesc);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                View setview = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("statutes", intent).getDecorView();
                setContentView(setview);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can't do this: View setview=getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("statutes", intent).getDecorView();
  setContentView(setview);

Comment: Yes, it's working but, it'll finished my app when i press back button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link out and download sample code provided in it and let me know for more requirements

[multiple activities in single tab](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

This code in this link also solves your problem

Comment: I've one bug with use of this method.

Comment: What kind of bug my friend let me know

Comment: I can't exit from my application.

Comment: For that you have to finish your tab activity I think. Just try to finish your tab activity which will ultimately finish your application